# elasticsearch indexing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-rails gem for an app. setup all code as required and mentioned in document. My question is whenever a new record is created how do you import new record data to elasticsearch. The model callbacks isnt working as expected.

```
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
```

Thanks,
Aashish

Comment: Could we see your model and how you're updating a record?

Comment: You also have to `include Elasticsearch::Model`

Answer (score 0):

You should include this in your model:

`include Elasticsearch::Model`

If you want to integrate with AR callback include this then:

`Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks`